# How can I use Greasemonkey to reorganize a <ul> list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, greasemonkey, userscripts

I tried to adapt someone's script from a Stack Overflow post, but I did something wrong. I've got essentially no experience with javascript or jQuery, so... Please help?

---

The target-page HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container7">
    <div class="userdata">
        <h4></h4>
        <ul id="userinfo" class="set textsize">
            <li class="name"></li>
            <li class="joindate"></li>
            <li class="title"></li>
            <li class="custom"></li>
            <li class="description"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to modify it to look like this:

```
<div class="container7">
    <div class="userdata">
        <h4></h4>
        <ul id="userinfo" class="set textsize">
            <li class="joindate"></li>
            <li class="name"></li>
            <li class="custom"></li>
            <li class="description"></li>
            <li class="title"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Reorganize li
// @namespace   blah
// @description Reorganize li
// @include     https://www.thewebsite.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var container    = document.querySelector (".userdata");
var firstTargDiv = container.querySelector (".userdata > li.name:first-child");
var lastTargDiv  = container.querySelector (".userdata > li.joindate:last-child");

//-- Swap last to first.
container.insertBefore (lastTargDiv, firstTargDiv);

//-- Move old first to last.
container.appendChild (firstTargDiv);
```

As a start -- just flipping the first two. It didn't work. I wasn't sure what I had done wrong. I've tried testing different `querySelector` values, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code would work (sort of) except that the CSS selectors, passed to `querySelector`, were off.  For the HTML you gave, they should be:

```
var container    = document .querySelector ("div.userdata > ul");
var firstTargDiv = container.querySelector ("li.name");
var lastTargDiv  = container.querySelector ("li.joindate");
```

Also, the `<li>`s would not have ended up quite where you wanted.

---

**To sort a uniform collection of nodes** just append them to the container in the order you want them.  Appending existing nodes just moves the nodes.

If your list of nodes (the `<li>`s in this case) each have a unique identifier or contained text, use an array to define an arbitrary sort order.
In this case, each `<li>` has a unique CSS class so we'll define the sort order like so:

```
var classOrder = ["joindate", "name", "custom", "description", "title"];
```

We can then use this array to snag each `<li>` by class and append it in the desired order.

Using jQuery, your complete userscript would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Reorganize li
// @include  https://www.thewebsite.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant GM_addStyle directive is needed to work around a design 
    change introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var classOrder  = ["joindate", "name", "custom", "description", "title"];
var containerNd = $("div.userdata > ul");

for (var J = 0, L = classOrder.length;  J < L;  J++) {
    var targetNode  = containerNd.find ('li.' + classOrder[J]);
    containerNd.append (targetNode);
}
```

You can [**see the code in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rfk32/).

Comment: Sweet! It works perfectly! Thanks for fixing the formatting of my question and providing such a helpful answer. I can easily refer back to this later on to understand the why/how of it working, and become a little more informed.

Side question: There are two <li> entries that don't have classes. Is there any way that I can grab them, or am I limited to classed <li>s?

Comment: The classless <li> entries are a *significant* complication (and an example of the danger of over-simplifying one's question). Open a new question for that, but try to solve it yourself first.  It may be that you can give those nodes a class using jQuery's `.addClass()` and then sort as above.